# Alternative to collosal blunder

Tags: word-usage

Is there any idiom or phrase to indicate someone's argument is obviously wrong,in a respectful way. I think the usage of **collosal blunder** in the below sentence sounds harsh.

Sentence:

> His argument falls into a **collosal blunder**

Comment: Arguments don't fall into blunders. What realm are we in? Got any context? Is it academic, philosophical or a fight over who baths the dog? His argument weakens, flags, loses its way, goes off the rails, goes astray, comes apart, falls apart; it becomes/grows less convincing/less persuasive, woolly, fallacious, faulty, less *than* convincing; it is up the creek, so much hot air; it lacks evidence, cogency... He is (clearly) mistaken in arguing/suggesting/proposing/saying...

Comment: Respectfully? "I think you have missed a point when you said..." and then leave them to realise the gravity of the error.